# Getting Err:502 with complex number functions using Librecalc 5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and LibreOffice 5.2. Some of my spreadsheets rely on complex numbers and I am getting `Err: 502` in the cells. These spreadsheets were working well with Ubuntu 14.04 and also run without issues on a Windows 10 platform. The behavior is strange as I will get `Err:502` with a simple function `=IMSUM(A1, B2)`  so there is no syntax error, however if I re-enter the formula the calculation works. When if I come back to the spreadsheet the cells will again show `Err:502`. Also a user-defined function that uses complex numbers and has worked for years, no longer works and a message box shows up

```
BASIC runtime error.
An exception occurred 
Type: com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message:
```

Comment: Recent version  of LO for Ubuntu is 5.1.4.2 from repository. Would you mind to try if you have the same issue with this version? You could try that easily without reinstalling LO if you use your Ubuntu-install-media and open the same spreadsheets in LO during the live-session.